# Cross compile to i686 on x86 macOS

Tags: rust, compilation, toolchain

I'm trying to cross compile a rust program to i686_unknown_linux_gnu with my x86 macbook.
I read https://blog.rust-lang.org/2016/05/13/rustup.html and found out that I need to get a linker for i686.

But there my journey ends. I can't find the i686 toolchain. 
Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I found a easy way to do what I want.
I'm using https://github.com/rust-embedded/cross which has the same behavior like cargo and does a good job.
There is no problem on my mac.